# Updating rather than replacing ECS Task Definition with CloudFormation

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, aws-cloudformation, amazon-ecs

When updating a TaskDefinition in CloudFormation the docs say that a replacement action occurs -
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-ecs-taskdefinition.html

Is there a way to get that to be a new revision? Should I be using the family parameter? Is there a TaskDefinition limit? Otherwise I end up with a large number of inactive definitions.

```
ContainerDefinitions:
  - Name: container
    Essential: 'true'
    Image: image:tag
    PortMappings:
      - ContainerPort: 80
        HostPort: 80
        Protocol: 'tcp'
    TaskRoleArn: 'arn:aws:iam::role'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, in order to put your changes in a new revision of the same Task Definition you should use the `Family` parameter. Quoting from the [official documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-ecs-taskdefinition.html):

> **Family**
>
> The name of a family that this task definition is registered to. A
>   family groups multiple versions of a task definition.

CloudFormation will still consider this a "replacement" and will delete the old revision, however it will not create a new Task Definition if you use the `Family` parameter.

Comment: Has anyone actually gotten Family to work as advertised? Even if I keep "Family" the same, updating the ContainerDefinition causes CloudFormation to trigger a replacement.

Comment: Did you find any dolution to this problem ?

Answer (score 1):

Actually, parameter Family , as decribed above is not working, even you inform it, Task Definition are replaced, but I saw in other thread ([here](https://serverfault.com/questions/878593/cloudformation-ecs-keep-all-taskdefinition-revisions)) that you can do it using following sintaxe in your template, observe UpdateReplacePolicy parameter

```
...
"Type": "AWS::ECS::TaskDefinition", 
"UpdateReplacePolicy": "Retain", 
"Properties": {
....
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).